# Prevent raising SelectionChanged event on a DataRow's Button click within a C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which has a Button column.

Each record in the DataGridView will have a separate Button.  A QueueMusic object containing Row-specific data should be queued upon clicking a Row's Button.

I currently have this working by placing a custom class (QueueMusic) onto a `Queue` collection using that collection's `.Enqueue()` method.

I have two event handler methods.

1. `DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged` method, which begins playing music associated the current Button's Row.
2. `DataGridViewAllMusic_CellClick` method, which handles queueing the playlist (defined within the QueueMusic class) that is associated with the current Button's Row.

**The Problem**

- Once music is playing, each subsequent click of a Row's Button interrupts the currently playing music with music defined by the newest Row's QueueMusic object.

I have a class QueueMusic.

```
    internal class QueueMusic
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int RowIndex { get; set; }

        public static Queue<QueueMusic> queulist = new Queue<QueueMusic>();
    }
```

and a DataGridView CellClickEvent

```
    private void DataGridViewAllMusic_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs 
     e)
    {

      var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

      if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 
       0)
       {
            QueueMusic qm = new QueueMusic();
            qm.RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            qm.Url = DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    
            QueueMusic.queulist.Enqueue(qm);
       }

     }


    private void DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      play();
    }
```

**Desired Behavior**

How can I prevent a Row's Button click event from being handled by `DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged` when music is already playing?

The desired behavior is to queue the next playlist in the background without inturrupting the currently playing playlist.

Comment: Which event is executed first?

Comment: SelectionChangedEvent

Comment: I do not mean any disrespect, however the `QueuMusic` Class looks very strange… “WHY” would EACH `QueueMusic` object contain a `Queue` “collection” of other `QueueMusic` objects … ? … This looks very odd and needs further explanation as to WHY this `Queue` collection `queuelist` property is there and how is it used? I am just saying that IMO each `QueueMusic` object only needs the `RowIndex`, since it can get the `Url` from the grid and the `RowIndex.` … ? …

Comment: Also in respect to your last sentence in the question… you should note that the grids `SelectionChanged` event will fire BEFORE the grids `CellClick` event is fired. So if the user clicked on a “BUTTON” cell that is currently NOT the selected row, then the grids `SelectionChanged` event will fire FIRST and execute the `play();` code. Then AFTER that, the grid will fire the `CellClick` event which appears to simply “queue up” the music on that row.

Comment: From the perspective of a user using a music player… if I am looking at a list of songs, then, single clicking on a row/song should NOT start playing the selected song… in most music players I have seen, if you want to “play” the song immediately, then you would need to “double-click” the song. Therefore, if you move the `play();` code to the grids `CellDoubleClick` event, then this should solve your current issue. Sorry if I am missing something and I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted several crucial parts of your code when writing your post here.

You need to include the `play()` method's logic.  Understanding what is happening there will greatly help us help you.

For example, what data comes from the URL that you inject into each instance of QueueMusic?

You'll definitely need to define a Form-level property to hold a single instance of whatever Queue or Music class you have.  Once instantiated on Form load, that object should only be added to when you click a Row's Button.  You'll need to handle Dequeueing playlists as they finish; maybe that's handled by other code that you didn't show.

The static Queue that you have defined inside of QueueMusic is not a good design.

Music playlists start over each time you click because you are overwriting the QueueMusic object on each click.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
internal class MusicQueue
{
    public MusicQueue() 
    {
        PlaylistQueue = new Queue<Playlist>();
        // any other setup...
    }
    public Queue<Playlist> Playlist { get; set; }
}

internal class Playlist
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public void Play() 
    {
        // ?
    }
    public bool IsPlaying { get; set; }
}
```

Within your Form's main class code, do the following:

```
...
private MusicQueue queue { get; set; }
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   queue = new MusicQueue();
   // any other setup...
}
...
```

Then within the two handlers:

```
private void DataGridViewAllMusic_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // get data from the DataGridView's Row
    
    // put the new playlist on the queue
    // you may want to check if the current Row's playlist is already on the queue
    queue.Playlist.Add(new Playlist() { (construct the new playlist here) };
 }


private void DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // depends on what `play()` is doing, but I'd probably
  // suggest checking if any playlist is playing.
  // if not, start the first playlist
  if (queue.Playlist.Any(p => p.IsPlaying)
  {
      queue.Playlist.FirstOrDefault().Play();
  }
}
```